# Database model: Name/Value pair

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm about to write an application where it should be possible to register information. The application should be able to use in many different areas, some of the values should be searchable and some not and therefore I have come up with the following database model:

```
           ----------
           |  Node  |
           ----------
                |
         ---------------
         |             |
     ---------     ---------
     |  Attr |     | IAttr |
     ---------     ---------
```

Attr Table is a table with atleast two columns Name and Value.
IAttr Table has the same setup with the difference that the Value column has an index on it.

Something tells me that this is not an good aproach to do this on, but I cant say why. I would like to get comments on if this is bad and why. The database that I would like to use is Oracle/MySQL or similar.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two tables? One if the user searches based on Name and the other if the user searches based on Value?

Comment: Why not add an index on Value in the Attr table itself?

Comment: Well what happends if the number of attributes grows quite much. My though by splitting them was that the index wouldnt grow so big.

Comment: You can still have two separate indexes on the same table. The appropriate index would be used depending on which column you use to search.

Comment: If "the number of attributes grows quite much", then you would be inserting the same data into two different tables, which would impact the performance.

Comment: How would splitting the table save the index from "growing so big"? Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: My though was that attributes that were to be searchable was placed in IAttr and attributes that are not searchable was places in Attr. But maybe im overthinking this. Lets say that the application should be able to handle 10.000.000 nodes and around 10-50 attributes per node, where around 5 should be searchable. So in total around 500.000.000 attributes and around 50.000.000 of these should be searchable.

Comment: @user3590032 Why not just have one table, and then index the columns that are searchable and not index the columns that are not?

Comment: @Branko, you'll still have an entry in the index for each row.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Not necessarily. Some DBMSes don't include NULLs in index (Oracle) and some offer filtered indexes that can achieve the same (MS SQL Server).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, this one's tagged MySQL.

Comment: @MarcusAdams The quote from the question: _"The database that I would like to use is Oracle/MySQL or similar"_.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting data between tables in that fashion is known as [partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) (horizontal, in this case), and [MySQL supports horizontal partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html).

You can certainly partition the data yourself and manage it in the application, or you can use the partitioning feature and let MySQL handle it for you.

If you use MySQL's partitioning, even though there will still be indexes on the non-searched values, you can keep the searched data in its own partition to keep that index at its minimum size, improving search performance.

Rolling out your own partitioning avoids the additional index on the non-searched table, which would improve write performance to said table as well as reduce the memory footprint, of course, at the cost of complexity in your code.

I would suggest that you avoid pre-optimization, and try to keep things as simple as you can for yourself. Only add complexity in the form of optimization if you really need to, and often that requires a lot of testing or real usage to determine the cost and value.

Either use MySQL's partitioning or none at all at first, then go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I totally agree with you that keeping it simple in the begining and build stuff when you need them. I just wanted to check that I was not going in the totally wrong direction. I have seen other implementations of standard systems where they do stuff abit diffrent, but thouse have a few years on them.